# How to get all Headings from pdf file using Itextsharp in c#

Tags: c#, itext

I need to get all heading from a pdf file, how to get all Headings from pdf file using  Itextsharp in c#?

Comment: How are your headings marked? Are they tagged accordingly to allow for selective extraction?

Comment: Yes Mkl i thinks its allow to extract, Heading simply like page header part..

Comment: Can you provide a sample file?

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you talking about "Artifacts"? Are you talking about titles (to be used for bookmarks or a TOC)? Also: you didn't answer mkl's question: is your PDF tagged?

Comment: YES Bruno iam talking about  titles (to be used for bookmarks or a TOC).

Comment: @Ashwani, just to be 100% clear, is there an explicit PDF instruction that you or someone else has written that says some block of text is a title? Or do you just have text that happens to be near the top of the PDF, possibly bold or in a larger font or something else that you consider to be the title? If you just have the latter then you'll need to apply your own logic (per PDF) about what distinguishes normal text from title text.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for your reply on this, i was waiting for your reply only,The problem is, i got all bookmarks in an pdf file but now i need to get their destination also.